# No response from devices under `Printers & scanners`

Tags: devicesanddrives

Under `Printers and Scanners`, I see the following devices:

- Fax
- HP PSC 750
- Microsoft Print to PDF
- Microsoft XPX Document Writer
- OneNote

No matter which one I click on, I am presented with the same two buttons: `Open queue` and `Manage`. No matter which button I press, nothing happens. If I double-click the device itself, nothing happens.

On the other hand, under `Bluetooth & other devices`, there is a `Devices and printers` which mysteriously can't be found if I type in either `printers` or `devices`. If I click on that, I get a `Devices and Printers` panel showing the same devices as above. I can actually double-click `HP PSC 750` and scan something.

**Why are there two different panels showing the same devices?**

**In Windows 10, is one more authoritative than the other?**

**Is the `Printers and Scanners` window *supposed* to be unresponsive?**

### BACKGROUND

I am on Windows 10 Pro 64-bit. In case the following might be relevant, I spent the last week trying to get the `HP PSC 750` recognized on this new Windows 10 laptop. I went to their [*Universal Print Driver for Windows*](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-universal-print-driver-series-for-windows/503548/model/4157320) and installed the *USB Driver*, which enabled printing but not scanning. Finally, I enabled *Receive updates for other Microsoft products...* under *Advanced options* for Windows updates and initiated an update. That enabled printing *and* scanning after unplugging and replugging the USB cable. I'm not sure if any of these steps might have caused the `Printers and Scanners` panel to be unresponsive.

Comment: @vssher: Thanks! Accessing `Printers and scanners` as Administrator did the trick.  Each device has options `Open queue`, `Manage`, and `Remove`.  `Remove` was not available when accessing `Printers and scanners` as non-Administrator.  I didn't try `Remove`, but both `Open queue` and `Manage` were responsive.  Neither are for actually using the device, e.g., to initiate a scan.

Comment: @vssher: I also tried `gpedit.msc` as Administrator, but I don't see the hierarchical path that you provided.  I found `Accounts: Administrator account status` under `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options`. After reading about it online, and considering my last comment above, I decided not to mess with it.

Comment: @vssher: Your second solution also worked: Under `Printers and scanners`, select the printer, then tab to the `Open queue` or `Manage` buttons and press `Return`.  Would you be so kind as to post your two "solution" as an answer?

Comment: If you can post your two solutions, I can mark it as the answer.  If you don't feel it worth the time, I'll post it.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank's for the update, I have posted all my comments into an Answer box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this computer, Windows 10 Professional, I have *Local Computer Policy* 
and also
 *Group Policy Editor*.

If you switch to log on using administrator account is the 
option working? Open **Local Secrutiy Policy** > Local Policies > 
Security Options > Accounts:

> Administrator account status + Enable +Disable.

A lot of people are having this same issue, even with the lastest Windows 
release. There is however a proposed workaround from *Bibs Rielley* Wednesday, September 18, 2019 [[1]](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef872c97-7d76-4c3c-a40f-ccc0d56850c3/windows-10-problem-with-printers-amp-scanners).

Comment: Thanks, vssher.  I found that Bibs Rielley's suggestion to tab to the `Open queue` and `Manage` buttons to be most convenient. Neither of them seem present the same functional options as accessing a device from the `Devices and scanners` panel, e.g. in the case of a PSC 750, to scan.

Comment: 2020-04-27: I tried for an hour to search for `Devices and scanners` without luck.  I was finally able to find myself to a familiar looking panel using [this recipe](https://superuser.com/questions/1546350/how-to-get-to-devices-and-scanners-rather-than-printers-scanners/1546353).  Not sure if `Devices and scanners` was a typo or whether the name of the panel changed.