# How to get to "Devices and scanners" rather than "Printers & scanners"

Tags: windows-10, usb, scanner, multi-function-printer

Since moving to Windows 10, I found it difficult to access the native scanning of my HP PSC 750.  Based on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1523726/no-response-from-devices-under-printers-scanners), I could access scanning from the "Devices and scanners" panel, but not from the "Printers & scanners" panel.  As of today, I can't even get to the "Devices and scanners" panel.  Everything I type into the Windows 10 search leads me to "Printers & scanners" instead.

How does one get to "Devices and scanners"?

What might have removed it (assuming it's gone)?

I can use somthing like Foxit Reader (free) to scan, but I don't find its controls as familiar.  Could the installation of Foxit Reader eliminated the entire "Devices and scanners" panel?

Comment: Go to the Microsoft Store, get HP Smart. Install it and set it up for your printer and it will offer native scanning. I use it myself.

Comment: Do you have a HP PSC 750?  I spent quite a dreadful week or more trying to get it to work, and don't relish the idea of going down that alley again.  Hence, the wish to be certain.  Thanks.

Comment: I do not have that particular model, but the HP Smart software is free and then see if if configures your printer. Costs nothing to try and little time. Printer configuration is easy - follow the prompts

Answer (score 0):

OK, this might save someone an hour.  It's incredible that there are two pathways to the same thing, but it is what it is.

Go to Start, type

1. `bluetooth and other devices` and click on the entry that comes up with that name
2. Under `Related settings`, click on `Devices and printers`

So simple, once you know the magical incantation.  And it looks like the panel is `Devices and printers`, *not* `Devices and scanners`.

I am not sure whether the latter was a typo or whether the panel name changed recently.  But it isn't heartening to realize that type `Devices and printers` from the Start menu doesn't turn up any hits.  Come on, Microsoft.

Something else that might save someone half an hour is that **if the printer/scanner/copier (PSC) doesn't show up with the above, I found that I had to plug the USB in to a very specific USB port on the laptop** (not just any of the USB ports) when the PSC was turned on.  It might be related to the version of USB supported by specific ports. Unfortunately, due to the amount of time lost to this, I'm not in a position to experiment, test, verify, and document.  Something to try, however...